# Splunk installation on top of Docker fails in AWS ec2 instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, ansible, splunk

I'm trying to install Splunk on top of Docker in an AWS ec2 instance using the following command.

```
docker run -it -e DEBUG=true -e SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license -e SPLUNK_PASSWORD=<password> splunk/splunk:latest
```

and I'm getting the following errors.

```
TASK [splunk_common : Create .ui_login] ****************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709", "msg": "Source /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566408647.18-207818394602441/source not found"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=18   changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=6    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Wednesday 21 August 2019  17:30:47 +0000 (0:00:00.377)       0:00:04.605 ****** 
=============================================================================== 
splunk_common : Update Splunk directory owner --------------------------- 1.04s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 0.74s
splunk_common : Update /opt/splunk/etc ---------------------------------- 0.52s
splunk_common : Create .ui_login ---------------------------------------- 0.38s
splunk_common : Check for existing installation ------------------------- 0.30s
splunk_common : Find manifests ------------------------------------------ 0.29s
splunk_common : Check if /sbin/updateetc.sh exists ---------------------- 0.15s
splunk_common : Check for existing splunk secret ------------------------ 0.13s
Provision role ---------------------------------------------------------- 0.13s
splunk_common : Check if we are in a docker ----------------------------- 0.13s
splunk_common : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.08s
splunk_common : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.08s
splunk_common : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.07s
splunk_common : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.07s
splunk_common : Set current version fact -------------------------------- 0.04s
splunk_common : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.04s
Determine captaincy ----------------------------------------------------- 0.04s
Execute pre-setup playbooks --------------------------------------------- 0.04s
splunk_common : Setting upgrade fact ------------------------------------ 0.04s
splunk_common : Set first run fact -------------------------------------- 0.04s
ERROR: Couldn't read "/opt/splunk/etc/splunk-launch.conf" -- maybe $SPLUNK_HOME or $SPLUNK_ETC is set wrong?
```

However, the same command works on an Ubuntu machine on my laptop. I'm missing anything?

Comment: Did you check the volume mounts in the host machine and Splunk instance ?. I guess, there could be some issue.

Comment: Yes. The volume mounts are configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have been an issue with the `latest` tag. Downgraded from `splunk/splunk:latest` to `splunk/splunk:7.2.1` and it works now.